# How to save and load Python Keras BERT model to serialize it?

Tags: python, keras, serialization, hdf5, bert-language-model

I've just finished to train my Keras BERT model which treats about multilabel Text classification  (percentage unit) and I would like to be able to applied my train model on new (unlabeled) text.

Here are main parts of my model :

```
   class BertLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(
        self,
        n_fine_tune_layers=10,
        pooling="first",
        bert_path="https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1", #This is the model we choose
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.n_fine_tune_layers = n_fine_tune_layers
        self.trainable = True
        self.output_size = 768
        self.pooling = pooling
        self.bert_path = bert_path
        if self.pooling not in ["first", "mean"]:
            raise NameError(
                f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}"
            )

        super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):

        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'n_fine_tune_layers': self.n_fine_tune_layers,
            'trainable': self.trainable,
            'output_size': self.output_size,
            'pooling': self.pooling,
            'bert_path': self.bert_path,
        })
        return config
    

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bert = hub.Module(
            self.bert_path, trainable=self.trainable, name=f"{self.name}_module"
        )

        # Remove unused layers
        trainable_vars = self.bert.variables
        if self.pooling == "first":
            trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars if not "/cls/" in var.name]
            trainable_layers = ["pooler/dense"]

        elif self.pooling == "mean":
            trainable_vars = [
                var
                for var in trainable_vars
                if not "/cls/" in var.name and not "/pooler/" in var.name
            ]
            trainable_layers = []
        else:
            raise NameError(
                f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}"
            )

        # Select how many layers to fine tune
        for i in range(self.n_fine_tune_layers):
            trainable_layers.append(f"encoder/layer_{str(11 - i)}")

        # Update trainable vars to contain only the specified layers
        trainable_vars = [
            var
            for var in trainable_vars
            if any([l in var.name for l in trainable_layers])
        ]

        # Add to trainable weights
        for var in trainable_vars:
            self._trainable_weights.append(var)

        for var in self.bert.variables:
            if var not in self._trainable_weights:
                self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)

        super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = [K.cast(x, dtype="int32") for x in inputs]
        input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = inputs
        bert_inputs = dict(
            input_ids=input_ids, input_mask=input_mask, segment_ids=segment_ids
        )
        if self.pooling == "first":
            pooled = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
                "pooled_output"
            ]
        elif self.pooling == "mean":
            result = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
                "sequence_output"
            ]

            mul_mask = lambda x, m: x * tf.expand_dims(m, axis=-1)
            masked_reduce_mean = lambda x, m: tf.reduce_sum(mul_mask(x, m), axis=1) / (
                    tf.reduce_sum(m, axis=1, keepdims=True) + 1e-10)
            input_mask = tf.cast(input_mask, tf.float32)
            pooled = masked_reduce_mean(result, input_mask)
        else:
            raise NameError(f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}")

        return pooled

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_size)




   

     # Build model
    def build_model(max_seq_length): 
        in_id = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="input_ids")
        in_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="input_masks")
        in_segment = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="segment_ids")
    
    #This is the input in list form to be fed to the model
    bert_inputs = [in_id, in_mask, in_segment]
    
    bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=3, pooling="first")(bert_inputs) #calling the preloaded BERT model we have installed
    
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(bert_output) # Attaching our model output here
    pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(possible_labels), activation='sigmoid')(dense)
    
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=bert_inputs, outputs=pred)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    
    return model


    def initialize_vars(sess):
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    K.set_session(sess)


    modll_ = build_model(max_seq_length)

    INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_impl.py:183: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_impl.py:183: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_ids (InputLayer)          [(None, 200)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_masks (InputLayer)        [(None, 200)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
segment_ids (InputLayer)        [(None, 200)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bert_layer (BertLayer)          (None, 768)          110104890   input_ids[0][0]                  
                                                                 input_masks[0][0]                
                                                                 segment_ids[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 256)          196864      bert_layer[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 17)           4369        dense[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 110,306,123
Trainable params: 22,055,441
Non-trainable params: 88,250,682
__________________________________________________________________________________________________


    # Instantiate variables
initialize_vars(sess)

    train_input_ids.shape, train_input_masks.shape, train_segment_ids.shape, train_labels.shape

    #Defining NBatchLogger for logging details for training
class NBatchLogger(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, display):
        self.seen = 0
        self.display = display

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.seen += logs.get('size', 0)
        if self.seen % self.display == 0:
            metrics_log = ''
            for k in self.params['metrics']:
                if k in logs:
                    val = logs[k]
                    if abs(val) > 1e-3:
                        metrics_log += ' - %s: %.4f' % (k, val)
                    else:
                        metrics_log += ' - %s: %.4e' % (k, val)
            print('{}/{} ... {}'.format(self.seen,
                                        self.params['samples'],
                                        metrics_log))


    out_batch = NBatchLogger(display=1000)

    modll_.fit([train_input_ids, train_input_masks, train_segment_ids], train_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT, callbacks=[out_batch])
```

Right after this code part I've tried :

```
modll_.save('model.h5') 

#from tensorflow.keras.models import  load_model
model = load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'BertLayer': BertLayer})
```

But I've got :

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'output_size')
```

During my researches for this error I read that it's simple to only save model weights so I tried :

```
modll_.save_weights('bert_weights.h5')

modll_.load_weights("bert_weights.h5")
```

Once modll_ weighs is conserved in the model I applied my model to a new text in order to obtain predication for it :

```
p_preds = modll_.predict([p_input_ids, p_input_masks, p_segment_ids])

pred_dict = {}
list_p = []

for i in p_preds:
    pred_dict['S1'] = str((i[0]*100)) + ' %'
    pred_dict['S2'] = str(i[1]*100) + ' %'
    pred_dict['S3'] = str(i[2]*100) + ' %'

   list_p.append(pred_dict)

for i in range(len(list_p)):
    print(list_p[i], "\n")
```

But I got very bad classification (I've tried for many text), which is surprising because during training phase I had 0.94 accuracy. I think that I've done mistakes when I saved and loaded my model. Any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

When loading the configuration and reconstructing the layers/models, the `config` dict returned from `get_config` will be applied to the constructor. In your case, this is similar to: `BertLayer(**config)`.

Since you don't have `output_size` in your constructor, you should either add the argument `output_size` to `__init__` (which is recommended because you shouldn't hard-coded the constant), or remove it from `get_config`.